# Why is my output intermittent?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I recently got an Altera DE0 nano board and have successfully implemented basic things such as counters and state machines. I'm now trying to implement a 1D Game of Life on the board's built in LEDs, which works correctly, but with a problem.

I want the game state to update at 1Hz (or arbitrarily fast), which this program does, except it also flashes the LEDs at the same frequency, so the LEDs blank for half a second before displaying the next state. I don't see what is wrong with the code but I suspect it's how I'm handling the 1Hz clock edge that's causing this problem.

Here is the current version of code:

```
----------------------------------
--      Library Declaration     --
----------------------------------
-- Like any other programming language, we should declare libraries

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

----------------------------------
--      Entity Declaration      --
----------------------------------
-- Here we specify all input/output ports

entity blinking_led is
    port(
        clk_50mhz : in std_logic ;
        reset_btn : in std_logic;
        green_leds : out unsigned(7 downto 0) := "11111111"
    );
end entity;

----------------------------------
--  Architecture Declaration    --
----------------------------------
--  here we put the description code of the design

architecture behave of blinking_led is

-- signal declaration

constant CLK_SPD : integer := 50000000;
constant N : integer := 8;

signal LED_init : unsigned(7 downto 0) := "00100100"; 
signal clk_1hz : std_logic ;
signal scaler : integer range 0 to 25000000 ;
signal out_register : unsigned(7 downto 0) := LED_init;
signal out_register_old : unsigned(7 downto 0) := "00000000";

begin

-- this process is used to scale down the 50mhz frequency
-- In reality, clk_1hz is not periodic but i used it to get 2 clock cycle by second ( 2 rising edge ).
-- 50 mhz means 50 000 000 cycle in one second : 
-- by using the scaler , i will have 2 cycle by second so that led will be on 1/2 s and off 1/2 s

    clk_1hz_process : process( clk_50mhz , reset_btn )
    begin
        if (reset_btn = '0') then 
            clk_1hz <= '0';
            scaler <= 0;
        elsif(rising_edge(clk_50mhz)) then 
            if (scaler < CLK_SPD/2) then 
                scaler <= scaler + 1 ;
                clk_1hz <= '0';
            else
                scaler <= 0;
                clk_1hz <= '1';
            end if;
        end if;
    end process clk_1hz_process;

    next_gen : process (clk_1hz,reset_btn, out_register, out_register_old)
    variable neighbours : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    variable rand_temp : std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0) := (N-1 => '1',others => '0');
    variable temp : std_logic := '0'; --(others => '0');

    begin
        --green_leds <= LED_init;
        if (reset_btn = '0') then 
            --green_leds <= LED_init;
            elsif clk_1hz'event and clk_1hz = '1' then

                out_register_old <= out_register;

                --Game rules:
                --Cells are connected on a N-entry long ring, so the first entry has its last as a neighbor and v/v
                --0 neighbors: no action
                --1 neighbor:  cell is born/stays alive
                --2 neighbors: cell dies

                for I in 0 to (N-1) loop
                    if(I = 0) then
                        neighbours := out_register_old(N-1) & out_register_old(I+1);
                    elsif(I > 0 and I < (N-1)) then
                        neighbours := out_register_old(I-1) & out_register_old(I+1);
                    elsif(I = N-1) then
                        neighbours := out_register_old(I-1) & out_register_old(0);
                    end if;

                    case neighbours is 
                        when "00" => out_register(I) <= out_register_old(I);
                        when "01" => out_register(I) <= '1';
                        when "10" => out_register(I) <= '1';
                        when "11" => out_register(I) <= '0';
                        when others => report "unreachable" severity failure;
                    end case;
                end loop;

                --PRNG for game reset logic 
                temp := rand_temp(N-1) xor rand_temp(N-2);
                rand_temp(N-1 downto 1) := rand_temp(N-2 downto 0);
                rand_temp(0) := temp;
--                  
--              if(out_register = 0) then
--                  --reset to random vector
--                  --out_register <= unsigned(rand_temp);
--                  out_register <= LED_init;
--              end if; 
--              
--              if(out_register = out_register_old) then 
--                  --stalemate, prepare to reset
--                  out_register <= "00000000"; 
--              end if;
--              
            end if;     
            green_leds <= out_register;
    end process next_gen;

    end behave;
```

I'm rusty with my VHDL so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know what is the game of life so I'm not sure how this should behave. However, it seems to me you may misunderstand the difference between signals and variables, and that out_register_hold should be a variable or not used altogether.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the code, the clk_1hz actually has two high pulses within one second (scaler < CLK_SPD/2), hence it should be clk_2hz. And the line

```
   green_leds <= out_register;
```

seems to be at a wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Although it may work, you shouldn't use a derived signal as clock, instead use the `clk_50mhz` through out and use `clk_1hz` as gating signal. Also you use the `reset_btn` once asynchronously (in `clk_1hz_process`) and once synchronosly (in `next_gen`) which may also lead to some funny effects.

```
next_gen : process 
-- ...
begin
    if(rising_edge(clk_50mhz)) then 
        if (reset_btn = '0') or (out_register = 0) then 
            -- synchronous reset and check for empty state in one
            out_register <= ...;
        elsif (clk_1hz = '1') then
             -- the main logic here
            out_register <= ...;
        else
            -- nothing happens here
        end if;
    end if;
end process;

-- output assignment
green_leds  <= out_register;
```

But most importantly, you are trying to use `out_register_old` in the same cycle where you also assign it (`out_register_old <= out_register`) , therefore it should be a variable (`out_register_old := out_register`); or it can just be replaced with `out_register` itself, since that will keep its old value until the end of the process.